# Specifying android permissions through gradle

Tags: gradle, permissions, manifest

I have:

```
product flavors {
    a { }
    b { }
}

buildTypes {
    1 { }
    2 { }
    releaseTest { }
}
```

Now I have a specific Manifest file I want to add to Flavor b & buildType Test, without putting it in the product Flavor b folder (I want it to be only going into androidTest, and I don't want to put it into the Flavor b folder as I may want it in flavor A as well but not in flavor B, while cutting builds, etc). Specifically all that's going to be in the manifest folder is a couple of permissions.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: see this https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-product-flavor-dependent-permissions